# How to update Delphi 10.4 Sydney installation?

Tags: delphi, installation, updates, delphi-10.4-sydney

I just installed the Windows development environment in Delphi 10.4 Sydney Enterprise from the downloaded ISO (execution of `radstudio_10_4_esd_99797b.exe`), followed by Update patch 1.

I forgot to check the *TeeChart standard* component and want to add that.

If I start the executable again it says:

> A previous version of RAD Studio 10.4 was found on your system that needs to be uninstalled first.

Given the time this will take I prefer not to uninstall.
Is there a way to update without uninstalling?

BTW I tried `radstudio_10_4_esd_99797b.exe -update` and `radstudio_10_4_esd_99797b.exe /update` but those did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Tools** menu option **Manage Platforms..** within Delphi can be used to bring up the same dialog as used during install to choose *Platforms* and *Additional Options*. The optional component TeeChart Standard is on the Additional Options tab.

[image]

Comment: A very obscure place to put option for modifying installation.

Comment: 'Manage Platforms' is now also available in the Welcome screen